# Unique id of class instance

Tags: c++, class, identifier

I have a class like this:

```
class ExampleClass {

private:
    int _id;
    string _data;

public:
    ExampleClass(const string &str) {
        _data = str;
    }
    ~ExampleClass() {

    }
    //and so on...    

}
```

How can I add unique(!) integer identifier (_id) for every instance of the class without using global variable?

Comment: "You can't" is the short answer, unless your `int` is wide enough to hold a pointer, and you use an ugly cast from `this`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, will every cast from 'this' to int be unique?

Comment: As long as `this` is unique, and `int` is wide enough to hold an int, according to the rules of math in this universe.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Hrmm, I like this 'this' solution. You can write it as an answer, if you'd like. Thank you!

Comment: The pointer to a *most derived object* is its unique ID, by definition. You can cast it to `uintptr_t`, but `int` might be too small.

Comment: @n.m. , will it be ok, if I use uint_64t? I have 64bit machine, so I assume so.

Comment: In practice yes, should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Use a private static member int, is shared among all instance of the class.
In static int in the constructor just increment it, and save it's value to your id member;

```
class ExampleClass {

private:
    int _id;
    string _data;
    static int counter=0;
public:
    ExampleClass(const string &str) {
        _data = str;
         id=++counter;
    }
```

**Update:**

You will need to take consideration in your copy constructor and operator= what behavior you want (depends on your needs, a new object or an identical one).

Comment: "contractor"? Haha... :-) ...PS: I am not the downvoter though

Comment: @WhiZTiM Thanks , however the answer is good.And I was the first

Comment: This does not compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d14ca035ec5a7be6

Answer (score 0):

You can hide a static data in your class, which will provide the unique id.

**Example:**

```
class ExampleClass {

private:
    int _id;
    static int idProvider;
public:
    ExampleClass(const string &str) 
          : _id(++idProvider)
    {} 
}

int ExampleClass::idProvider = 0;
```

the logic is everytime you created an object of `ExampleClass` it will increment the `idProvider` which will then assign as a unique id to your `id`

Comment: I had this in mind, but the problem is I don't know how big dataset will be. Of course I can hope that _id is big enough to keep really long numbers...

Comment: @kekyc, then use a `std::uint64_t` (typically an `unsigned long long`)... Which will have a maximum value of about `18446744073709551615`... If your dataset is bigger than that.... Then you may want to rethink your design holistically... Perhaps use a UUID?

Comment: @WhiZTiM I eventually decided to cast 'this' pointer to _id because it is unique during the current instance exists and also it has certain range, depending on my system, so I avoid the type overflow in principal.
Anyway, thank you for your answer! (If you have something to say about this 'this' solution, I'd like to hear it).