# initializing a static (non-constant) variable of a class.

Tags: c++, class, variables, static

I have TestMethods.h

```
#pragma once

// strings and c-strings
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

class TestMethods
{
private:
    static int nextNodeID;
    // I tried the following line instead ...it says the in-class initializer must be constant ... but this is not a constant...it needs to increment.
    //static int nextNodeID = 0;
    int nodeID;

    std::string fnPFRfile; // Name of location data file for this node.


public:
    TestMethods();
    ~TestMethods();

    int currentNodeID();
};

// Initialize the nextNodeID
int TestMethods::nextNodeID = 0;
// I tried this down here ... it says the variable is multiply defined.
```

I have TestMethods.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestMethods.h"

TestMethods::TestMethods()
{
    nodeID = nextNodeID;
    ++nextNodeID;
}
TestMethods::~TestMethods()
{
}
int TestMethods::currentNodeID()
{
    return nextNodeID;
}
```

I've looked at this example here: [Unique id of class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444153/unique-id-of-class-instance)

It looks almost identical to mine.  I tried both the top solutions.  Neither works for me.  Obviously I'm missing something.  Can anyone point out what it is?

Comment: Whats the problem with using `static int nextNodeID = 0;` in the class?  You can still increment it in your constructor.

Comment: 1) "_I tried this down here ... it says the variable is multiply defined._" Don't define the variable in the header - do it in the .cpp file, so it is defined only once. 2) "_it says the in-class initializer must be constant_" Are you compiling with C++-11 enabled? If I remember correctly, such syntax was invalid before C++-11.

Comment: Nathan, the problem is that it says "a member with an in-class initializer must be const" ... but this is not intended to be a constant.

Comment: Algirdas, If I put it outside the class definition, it's no longer a private variable.  However, I tried that and it works.  
I don't know how to tell what version of C++ I'm compiling to.  I just installed VS community 2017.  There is nothing entered in the "C++ Language Standard"

Comment: Oh, oops. Forgot that in class initialization still doesn't apply for non-const static members

Comment: *"If I put it outside the class definition, it's no longer a private variable"* - what are you talking about? It's still a private static member, even if you're simply moving the initial value to the definition rather than the declaration. And the definition, `int TestMethods::nextNodeID = 0;`, should be in *one* cpp file. That doesn't belong in the header.

Comment: Whoz, you're right. I see how that makes sense.  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the definition of `TestMethods::nextNodeID` into the cpp file.  If you have it in the header file then every file that includes the header will get it defined in them leading to multiple defenitions.

If you have C++17 support you can use the `inline` keyword to declare the static variable in the class like

```
class ExampleClass {

private:
    inline static int counter = 0;
public:
    ExampleClass() {
        ++counter;
    }
};
```